# Finite set of points as hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{A}^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

We know that finite set of points $(a_1,b_1),\ldots,(a_n,b_n)$ in $\mathbb{A}^2(\mathbb{R})$ are hypersurfaces. In deed, if we consider $$f=\prod_{i=1}^n((x-a_i)^2+(y-b_i)^2),$$
then we would have that $\{(a_1,b_1),\ldots,(a_n,b_n)\}=V(f)$.

My question here is, ¿Is it possible to obtain the same result for $f$ irreducible? So that every finite set of points in $\mathbb{A}^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a hypersurface of an irreducible polynomial.

Comment: How about $f^2 + g^2 = 0$ for $f,g$ polynomials? The zeroes will be $f=g=0$ and I am going to guess that $f^2+g^2$ is generically irreducible. Probably you can fit such a curve to any set of points by being very careful.

Comment: I think that the zeroes here will mix and produce more than we want.

Comment: @FRANCISCOGALLARDO What do you mean by "the zeroes will *mix*"? The polynomials $f$ and $g$ presumably have real coefficients, so that for any specific $x$ one has $[f(x)]^2+[g(x)]^2=0$ iff both $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=0.$

Comment: Maybe i am not understanding what you mean... First, I do not know why you put them in terms of x, as they are two-variable polynomials.

Answer (score 2):

Any finite set of points in the plane over an infinite field, after a change of variables can be assumed to lie on $y=0$. So, they are of the form $(a_i,0)$. So, they lie on the irreducible curve when the field is the reals, $p(x)^2+y^2$ where $p(x)=\prod (x-a_i)$.

I explain my first sentence as asked by the OP.

Let $(a_i,b_i)$ be the points with coordinates in the infinite field $K$. For any pair $i,j$, there can be at most one $t\in K$ such that $a_i+tb_i=a_j+tb_j$. Since the field is infinite, there is some $u\in K$ so that $a_i+ub_i\neq a_j+ub_j$ for any $i\neq j$. So, after a change of variables, we may assume all the $a_i$s are distinct. Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n-1$ where $n$ is the number of points. We solve for the coefficients of $p$ from the equations $b_i=p(a_i)$ for all $i$ which just uses the fact that van der Monde matrices are invertible, since $a_i$s are distinct. Then your points lie on $y=p(x)$ and then a change of variables make this curve to be $y=0$.

Comment: Thx, that is much more clear!